# Error message not working properly in ngx-datatable

Tags: angular, angular5, ngx-datatable

I am currently working with ngx-datatable.

I collect data after subscribe and store it in dataRows:

```
this.dataRows = res.data.items;
```

which then passed to ngx-datatable

```
<ngx-datatable
            class="bootstrap"
            [rows]="dataRows"
            [columns]="dataColumns"
            [columnMode]="'force'"
            [headerHeight]="50"
            [selectionType]="'single'"
            [selected]="selected"
            (select)="recordSelected()"
            [messages]="{emptyMessage: 'Data not found!', totalMessage: 'total'}"
            [count]="totalItems"
            >
        </ngx-datatable>
```

My problem is if dataRows is empty, it shows empty Message but I receive error message too

```
core.js:1350 ERROR TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
```

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with your sintax, you have used it as in manual:

```
[messages]="{emptyMessage: 'There are no records...'}"
```

As @suraz suggested, check for other possible errors

Answer (score 0):

check by using  if condition..
 for example
if( data !== null){

this.dataRows = data;

}